# Calculate a line integral of the first kind

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Calculate the curvilinear integral of the first kind $\int_{C}ydl$, where $C: x^2 + y^2 = ax$

**Solvement**
$$x^2 - ax + \frac{a^2}{4} - \frac{a^2}{4} + y^2 = 0$$
$$(x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + y^2 = \frac{a^2}{4}$$
Let's introduce the replacement:
$$x - \frac{a}{2} = \frac{a}{2}\cos(t), y = \frac{a}{2}\sin(t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$
$$x = \frac{a}{2}(\cos(t) + 1), y = \frac{a}{2}\sin(t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$

$$dl = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}(\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t))}dt = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}}dt = \frac{a}{2}$$

Let's substitute all this into our original integral.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{a}{2}\sin(t)\frac{a}{2}dt = \frac{a^2}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin(t)dt = 0$$

Please tell me if I solved this curvilinear integral correctly? Unfortunately, I didn’t understand this topic well, can you please suggest resources where I can better understand this?

Comment: **Note**: The bounds for $\phi$ are wrong. $C$ is a circle, but the center of a circle is **not** the origin.

Comment: To @NickSchemov: Next, rather think about different parametrization which will better suit a given circle.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, $x^2 - ax + \frac{a^2}{4} - \frac{a^2}{4} + y^2 = 0$,  $(x - \frac{a}{2})^2  + y^2 =  \frac{a^2}{4}$. Than we can choose $x - \frac{a}{2} = \cos(t)$, $y = \sin(t)$, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. will this parameterization be better?

Comment: It is correct, and at least in many cases will help better. BTW your try with polar coordinates was also OK, but your bounds were incorrect.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, I fixed the solution, but the answer looks strange. It looks like I made a mistake somewhere again, can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: To @NickSchemov: for a curve $\left(x - \frac{a}{2}\right)^2+y^2 = \frac{a^2}{4}$ I would use this parametrization: $x=x(t)=\frac{a}{2}(\cos t + 1), \, y=y(t)=\frac{a}{2}\sin t$.